# How can we get exact time to load a Mobile Application page using Appium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

> Hi Team, I need to calculate the Mobile app Page loading time when we navigate from one screen to other screen for Mobile Application.

**I have Tried below Approach:**

Before Clicking on Element, get the current Time in MS and after clicking on the element, Waiting for expected element to be visible then again getting current time in MS and Subtract the times.

Please Help me out with better approach to calculate accurate page load time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get('url')
navigationStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
responseStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.responseStart")
domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")
 
backendPerformance_calc = responseStart - navigationStart
frontendPerformance_calc = domComplete - responseStart
 
print("Back End: %s" % backendPerformance_calc)
print("Front End: %s" % frontendPerformance_calc)
```

You can use this for page loads. Not sure of the Java way for this.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeAsyncScript("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the duration.
Start stopwatch when you start loading the application/page.
And stop it when the last element is loaded.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, but other answers have more detailed solutions on how to solve this problem using the tagged frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can find the exact time of loading a homepage by using stopwatch class.
Use below code:

StopWatch loadTime = new StopWatch();

```
    driver.get("url");
    loadTime.start();
    
    boolean appLoaded = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.xpath("any xpath of expected page"))).isDisplayed();
    
    loadTime.stop();
    
    System.out.println("is App loaded : " +appLoaded);
    long pageLoadTime_ms = loadTime.getTime();
    System.out.println(" Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_ms + " milliseconds");
```